# Using User Managed Identity in Azure function Service Bus triggers not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity

I have a function that uses Service bus trigger and wanted to use "User Managed Identity". I couldn't get this working even after following all the config settings.
Below is the config I am using :

The Function trigger looks like:

```
public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusUsrIdty")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage[] servBusRcvMsg, ILogger log)
```

In the App settings:

```
ServiceBusUsrIdty__fullyQualifiedNamespace = <service bus namespace>.servicebus.windows.net
ServiceBusUsrIdty__clientId = <client id of the user managed identity>
ServiceBusUsrIdty__credential = "managedidentity"
```

With the above setting, I couldn't get it working and I then added the below as well but no luck
AzureWebJobsServiceBusUsrIdty = "Endpoint=sb://.servicebus.windows.net/;Authentication=ManagedIdentity"

I am using the package : Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus v7.5.1
The User managed identity is added in the Function App settings and it was granted "Contributor" access in the service bus

What else am I missing to get this working ? The documentation from Microsoft doesn't sufficient details though.

Comment: How exactly this is not working ? can you share the full error message ?

Comment: Did you mean this for the credential:
ServiceBusUsrIdty__credential = "managedidentity"

Comment: Please review your last edit. It seems you accidentally undid a helpful formatting improvement by another user.

Answer (score 1):

There is slight syntax mistake in the Service Bus connection stored in the '`AzureWebJobsServiceBusUsrIdty`'.

It means the connection string must have a space between "`Managed`" and "`Identity`", i.e.

```
Endpoint=sb://myendpoint.servicebus.windows.net/;Authentication=Managed Identity
```

Include the space for the Authentication value as shown above and run the function.

Refer [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/64363#issuecomment-708429289) for more information

Comment: this config is no longer needed, read my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73915471/azure-function-how-to-use-defaultazurecredential-for-development-using-visual-st/73923703#73923703

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you should need anything other than your ServiceBusUsrIdty__fullyQualifiedNamespace setting. I have a .net 6 Azure Function that is connecting to Service Bus without issue with just that setting. Within your code you should only need to reference "ServiceBusUsrIdty" in the Connection parameter of the ServiceBus attribute, e.g. *Connection = "ServiceBusUsrIdty"*. The "__fullyQualifiedNamespace" in essence tells the library that you are using Managed Identity.

Do you have Identity turned on for the Function and have you granted that Managed Identity access to Service Bus via one of the roles under Access control (IAM), e.g. "Azure Service Bus Data Receiver" and "Azure Service Bus Data Owner"?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add "**Azure Service Bus Data Receiver**" role.

Also check what version of the sdk you are using, you will need Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus Version="5.2.0" or higher

These resources might help.

[Azure Service Bus trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#service-bus-extension-5x-and-higher)

[Azure Functions developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob#common-properties-for-identity-based-connections)